# How to route SMTP traffic for my exchange virtual machine which hosted on my ubuntu server which is acting as a router\firewall behind my ADSL router

Tags: networking, server, email, firewall, router

I'M new to the whole operation what I have is Ubuntu server 18.04 which act as a Router\firewall and DHCP server for my network same server host a virtual machine holding Microsoft Exchange 2013 how I can shift SMTP traffic from my ADSL router which have a static public IP (A record and MX record already published) through Ubuntu server(another Router\Firewall) to land on my exchange server.. this is needed to activate mail receiving function.

Else this is what I did in ADSL Router under NAT option I activated port forwarding to Ubuntu server (router\firewall) external IP address and in Ubuntu server I used below commands to shift traffic to my VM

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.30:25
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.10.10.30 --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

but still not working what I missed here ?

Comment: See "Network address translation" & "Port forwarding". In short, on your DSL gateway, add a port forwarding (TCP/25) to your Ubu server. On the server iptables, accept TCP/25 and forward it to your MS VM

Comment: OK I already did all that .. in ADSL Router under NAT option I activated port forwarding to Ubuntu server (router\firewall) external IP address and in Ubuntu server I used below commands to shift traffic to  my VM                                             # iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.30:25
# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.10.10.30 --dport 25 -j ACCEPT  but still not working what I missed here ?

Comment: please [edit] your question, provide all needed information to help... Does the Ubu server be able to reach the VM port TCP/25?

Comment: Thanks I already did what you recommend regarding question editing, Else how I can test if Ubu server be able to reach the VM port TCP/25 ? Also is routing tables correct ? and what should I do to make sure it's up and running?

Comment: test if a specific port is reachable with `telnet`, `nc` or `nmap`

Comment: tried to test with: curl 10.10.10.30:25 and result was: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.10.10.30 port 25: Connection refused, please help